# Using dlmwrite to write cell objects MATLAB

Tags: file, matlab, cells

I have a cell array with 7 columns. All these columns contain strings. I want to write this cell array into a text file. To start, I was doing this on only 1 element of the cell and this is my code:

```
 dlmwrite('735.txt',cell{1},'delimiter','%s\t');
```

`cell{1}` looks like this:

`Columns 1 through 2`

```
[1x30 char]    [1x20 char]
```

`Column 3`

```
'Acaryochloris'
```

`Column 4`

```
'Cyanobacteria001'
```

`Columns 5 through 6`

```
'Cyanobacteria00'    'Cyanobacteria'
```

`Column 7`

```
'Bacteria'
```

It gives me the output without separating the columns. Sample output is:
         `Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017AcaryochlorismarinaAcaryochlorisCyanobacteria001Cyanobacteria00CyanobacteriaBacteria`

The correct output should have spaces between all the columns :

`Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017 Acaryochloris_marina Acaryochloris Cyanobacteria001 Cyanobacteria00 Cyanobacteria Bacteria`

Note that for the second column, we need to add the underscore between `Acaryochloris` and `marina`. There is originally a space between those two words.

I hope I explained the problem correctly, Would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you opening `out.txt`? DLMWRITE does not need `fopen` call.

Comment: Yeah true, I meant to delete that. I was trying `fprintf` first

Comment: You can edit your question to remove those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLMWRITE is for numerical data. In your case it process the char data as numbers, each character as a time. You probably view the resulted file in such a way that you don't see tab delimiters.

You can use XLSWRITE to write cell string array to a file. If you don't want the output to be in Excel format, run DLMWRITE before it to write some number to a file.

```
dlmwrite(filename,1)
xlswrite(filename, Acell{1})
```

Don't call you variable cell, which a keyword in MATLAB.

As an alternative you can write to a file with lower level function, like FPRINTF.

**UPDATE**:

If you want to use XLSWRITE in a for-loop and not to overwrite the data you can specify the row to start from:

```
dlmwrite(filename,1)
for k = 1:10
    xlswrite( filename, Acell{k}, 1, sprintf('A%d',k) )
end
```

---

**UPDATE 2**:

Unfortunately it does not work anymore in the latest MATLAB releases (I believe starting from R2012b). XLSWRITE gives error about wrong file type.

Comment: Wait, how does running `dlmwrite` before `xlswrite` change the file format from Excel to whatever?

Comment: Just try to run it. Apparently xlswrite recognizes the file format and doesn't change it.

Comment: hmm true. If I want to do this for a bunch of files and keep the `xlswrite` command in a for loop...will it automatically update the row number? aka write the new data in the next row? I am in the process of running it with 1200 files, but just wanted to be sure as the file preview shows that the data is probably being over-written to the same row.

Comment: Yup, just over-wrote it. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of the following should do what you want:

```
fid = fopen('735.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\t', cell{1}{:});
fclose(fid);
```